# Replace hard disk preserving symlinks

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, symbolic-link

I have to replace my secondary hard drive because it seems to have some problems. I would like to clone the partitions to a new hard drive.

I have some symlinks that point to the secondary HD (e.g. I have moved some directories from AppData in a partition of secondary HD and linked with symlink).

My question is: if I clone the partitions to a new HD and I replace the the HD, the symlinks from C: partition to the old HD partitions are preserved?

My OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinks/junctions will still point to the same place where before. If you copy or clone your data and put it where it was, nothing will change. Neither for file system, nor for you.
Let's assume `C:` is your system drive, `D:` is your HD you want to replace, `E:` is your new drive.
(pseudo shell code; `\>` is command prompt, `#` is comment)
#
there is a link:

```
\> dir
C:\user\stuff -> D:\stuff
```

now copy/clone to E:

```
\> copy D:\stuff E:\stuff
```

Remove disk D: and place E: "in its place". You may need change drive letter of your new drive (`E:`) to `D:`. Do it @ `control panel -> administrative tools -> computer management -> disk management`; or from command line

```
\> mmc.exe "C:\WINDOWS\system32\compmgmt.msc"
```

Now your symbolic link/s (`C:\user\stuff`) points to actual data (`D:\stuff`).

Job's done.

Comment: Thanks. I have cloned my partitions to another HD and replaced, all works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Every link (junction Points and SymLinks) be cloned to the new drive. Certainly you should use cloning software and not just copy files and folders.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try...